# C# Identity, .NET6 - Why IsInRoleAsync doesn't work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-6.0, identity

userManager.IsInRoleAsync always return FALSE.

When I add role to user and then check if user has role it return false

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDqhV.png)

my identity configuration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9zX9.png)

I'm using .NET6

I can add role to user, but when I want to check if user is in role (IsInRoleAsync) it return false and when I want to remove role from user (RemoveFromRoleAsync) it says that user is not in role.

Function GetUsersInRoleAsync also work normally. Only this two function dosen't work IsInRoleAsync, RemoveFromRoleAsync. Do I need to configure something?

Comment: You're probably not implementing role manager only user manager; hence your roles appearing in user manager and not role manager.

Comment: Code is just text so show that and not pictures of text.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I tried with roleManager too. Why other function works and IsInRole not?

Comment: Please, post code as text, not as a picture.

Comment: Hi @TheMadMattt, Can you tell us how did you add the user to the role? Perhaps you are setting the roles directly from the database, in this scenario, the `IsInRoleAsync` or `RemoveFromRoleAsync` method might not work. To solve it, you can try to use `UserManager.AddToRoleAsync()`/`UserManager.AddToRolesAsync()` method to add user to the role, then you can use `IsInRoleAsync` and `RemoveFromRoleAsync` method to check if user in role or remove from the specified role.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add this services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
in the ConfigureService method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
...
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>();
...
}
```

Comment: It's not working, IsInRole also returns false